# How to realize the same effect like iPhone's homescreen

Tags: iphone, uitableview, homescreen

I want to add some custom buttons and realize the same effect like the iPhone's home screen. What I can think of is to calculate the position of each button and add them to the view. Are there any other ways to do this? e.g. add buttons to the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the same view of the thumbnails in the photo app (which in principle differs only because of the background color and the rounded effect of the buttons) using a custom cell (with 4 UIButtons inside) in a normal tableview.

In my case, this is because I need to scroll up and down, in your specific case there should be a way to "lock" the table from scrolling. By the way, for this reason, it could be simpler to design the custom view in the interface builder, it is very quick to design such a view, and then create a custom controller to provide simple methods to assign icons and actions to the UIButtons dynamically.

You could also look at the Three20 libraries as already suggested, it is already implemented, but you app will easily be rejected by Apple if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Check `TTLauncherView` from [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20),